# Retrieve Data from SQLite Database according to Firstname

Tags: android, database, sqlite

```
    **DBAdapter.java :**

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

                db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_FIRSTNAME
                        + " TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_MIDDLENAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                        + KEY_LASTNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_USERNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_MAIL_ID + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                        + KEY_PASSWORD + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_CONFIRM
                        + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_DATE_OF_BIRTH
                        + " INTEGER NOT NULL "
                        + ");");

            }

        public long insertRecord(String firstname, String middlename,
                String lastname, String username, String mail_id, String pass_word,
                String re_password, String d_o_b) {

            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(KEY_FIRSTNAME, firstname);
            cv.put(KEY_MIDDLENAME, middlename);
            cv.put(KEY_LASTNAME, lastname);
            cv.put(KEY_USERNAME, username);
            cv.put(KEY_MAIL_ID, mail_id);
            cv.put(KEY_PASSWORD, pass_word);
            cv.put(KEY_CONFIRM, re_password);
            cv.put(KEY_DATE_OF_BIRTH, d_o_b);
            //cv.put(KEY_COUNTRY, coun_try);
            return mDB.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

        }

    public String getName() {


            String column[] = new String[] { KEY_FIRSTNAME, KEY_MIDDLENAME,
                    KEY_LASTNAME };
            Cursor c = mDB.query(DATABASE_TABLE, column, null, null, null, null,
                    null);
            String name = "";
            int iFirst = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_FIRSTNAME);
            int iMiddle = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_MIDDLENAME);
            int iLast = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_LASTNAME);
            for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
                name = name + c.getString(iFirst) + "\t" + c.getString(iMiddle)
                        + "\t" + c.getString(iLast) + "\t";
            }
            c.close();
            return name;

        }



----------


    **Profile_view.java :**

    DBAdapter dbAdapter = new DBAdapter(Profile_view.this);
            dbAdapter.open();
            String name = dbAdapter.getName();
            full_name.setText(name);
            username_display.setText(dbAdapter.getUserName());
            mail_display.setText(dbAdapter.getMail_id());
            date_of_birth_display.setText(dbAdapter.get_date_of_birth());


----------
```

> I am able to store the data and retrieve the data from database but while retrieving it

shows all the data that was previously stored but it is supposed to show only the one that

i inserted then. Basically if a user logins with his username, it is supposed to show only

his profile details but it shows all the entries in database. How am  i supposed to

segregate it according to first name or any specific entry(primary key i believe). Sorry

for posting such a silly question but i am totally new to programming and database. Any

help is highly appreciated.

Comment: @bobby.dhillon Thanks pal. As i am new to programming, that code seems too tough for my tiny lil brain but none the less, appreciate your effort. Cool..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Profile_view.java you would call the method passing the String to be matched:**

```
String name = dbAdapter.getName(currentUser);
```

**Your adjusted getName method should look something like this:**

```
public String getName(String currentUser);
```

**FInally, the SQLiteDatabase class' query method you're calling is defined like this:**

query(String table, String[] columns, **String selection**, **String[] selectionArgs**, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy)

**So adjust the query call to look like this:**

```
Cursor c = mDB.query(DATABASE_TABLE, column, null, "where firstname = ?", new String[]{"" + currentUser + ""}, null, null);
```

**Making things more dynamic:**

```
String where = "where " + columnToMatch + " = ?";
Cursor c = mDB.query(DATABASE_TABLE, column, null, where, new String[]{"" + stringToMatch + ""}, null, null);
```

This way you can call query() returning whatever you want. **Your new get method could be:**

```
public String getSomething(String currentUser, String columnToMatch);
```

Comment: But Mr.Bennet, that method is just one example of several methods that i have implemented in my class. I also have getmailid(),getusername(),getdob() and so on.

Comment: Thanks Mr.B, Will try that and get back to ya.  Much obliged.

Comment: This will return any (could be null) matches to your defined currentUser variable. So testing the Cursor for null before returning would be smart.

Comment: My Cursor wants to rearrange the arguments like this Cursor c = mDB.query(DATABASE_TABLE,column,null,new String[]{"" + currentUser + ""},where,null,null); Is it ok ??

Comment: Check out the class definition for SQLiteDatabase here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html - the cursor shouldn't want to rearrange anything. It holds results, hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Quick suggestion add id as primary key column to users table. Then get that id after new record is inserted and save that id in SharedPreferences, then when ever required you can pull record from users table like using WHERE `id` = my_id_save. 
Here is example http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

Answer (score 1):

You are retrieving all rows for the three columns you specified in the `columns` array because you passed `null` for your `WHERE` clause in your call to `query()`.

Comment: So you're suggesting that i replace the null in the query method ?

Comment: yes, you should replace the `null` that is the parameter for the `WHERE` clause. You should retrieve the user whose password and username match what was entered by the user.

Answer (score 1):

Use the WHERE clause, you can then filter your results to be retrieved.

May I suggest you take a look at [cupboard](http://code.neenbedankt.com/introducing-cupboard-simple-persistance-for-android/), it'll make your code much more readable and makes the whole database usage much simpler!